# How to make the HTML container and iframe embedded in it, exactly the same size

Tags: html, css, processing, p5.js

I created a simple sketch with the [P5.js web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/) which I would like to embed into my website.
The canvas of my test sketch has a height and widht of 300px. 
[This](https://jsfiddle.net/Kubismus/6sq0paxj/) is what the sketch looks light when I simply drop it on a website and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Kubismus/08b9nkw5/) is what it looks like when I add some simple CSS. Here is my code:

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block
}


#canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
      <iframe src="https://editor.p5js.org/Kubi/embed/BkuSPoiZ4" frameBorder="0" id="canvas"></iframe>
</div>
```

Although I manually set the size of the `#canvas` element to 300 x 300px, the outer `#container` is visibly larger and has a height of 304 px. 
Why is this the case? How can I make the `#container` the exact same size as the iFrame without manually having to also set the size of `#container`?

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of your problem markup or code **here within your question**, not a third party site, that allows us to duplicate the issue: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you set a border of 2px on each side for the container: `border: 2px solid blue;` this expands the container 4px (2px on the left and 2px on the right) hence the 304px width. You could change your CSS to the following to get a 300x300 px container:

```
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

The `line-height` removes the space that all elements have at the bottom for minimal space between lines.

Comment: Thank you, the line-height attribute solved my problem. The width was not affected by the border.